# Router navigate not loading component the first time

Tags: javascript, angular, meteor, angular2-routing

I'm having an issue with my Angular2/Meteor application.
I'm trying to redirect to a component from an other but it doesn't seem to load the first time. However, when I refresh the page, it loads perfectly.
When I debug, I see my html view without any of the variables displaying, my variables have values that seems correct, but they doesn't show on the View.

This is my Guard:

```
import { CanActivate } from "@angular/router";
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class RouteGuardService implements CanActivate {

    constructor(public router: Router) { }
    canActivate() {
        if (Meteor.userId() != undefined) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            let link = ['accueil'];
            this.router.navigate(link);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

My route.module :

```
import { Route } from '@angular/router';
import {AccueilComponent} from "./pages/accueil/accueil.component";
import {ChannelsComponent} from "./pages/channel/channels.component";
import { RouteGuardService } from './services/routeGuard.service';

export const routes: Route[] = [
    { path: '', component: AccueilComponent },
    { path: 'accueil', component: AccueilComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'channel', component: ChannelsComponent, canActivate: [RouteGuardService], pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

I hope I was clear with my explanation. Do not hesitate to ask more information.
Thanks !

EDIT: 
My app.module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Ng2DragDropModule } from 'ng2-drag-drop';
import { AccountsModule } from 'angular2-meteor-accounts-ui';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MomentModule } from "angular2-moment";
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-modialog';
import { BootstrapModalModule } from 'ngx-modialog/plugins/bootstrap';
import { ChannelModal } from './pages/channel/channel_search/channel-list.modal';
import { RouteGuardService } from './services/routeGuard.service';

import { AccueilComponent } from "./pages/accueil/accueil.component";
import { LOGIN_DECLARATIONS } from './pages/login';
import { CHANNEL_DECLARATIONS } from './pages/channel';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        Ng2DragDropModule.forRoot(),
        ModalModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserModule,
        AccountsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MomentModule,
        BootstrapModalModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AccueilComponent,
        ...LOGIN_DECLARATIONS,
        ...CHANNEL_DECLARATIONS,
        ChannelModal
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ChannelModal
    ],
    providers:[
        RouteGuardService
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Try to use '/' in front of routes like this  this.router.navigate('/accueil');

Comment: I tried but it didn't work :(

Comment: Try to use like this this.router.navigate(['/accueil]);

Comment: Tried too, not working :(

Comment: can you post app.module code

Comment: Yes sur, it's done

Comment: Trace the route by using this code imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )

Comment: I traced it, and it's the correct route that is displayed :(
Router Event: NavigationEnd
NavigationEnd(id: 2, url: '/channel', urlAfterRedirects: '/channel')
NavigationEnd {id: 2, url: "/channel", urlAfterRedirects: "/channel"}

Comment: study this link https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: I kind of already did it before I post my problem. Maybe I missed something in the publication ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found an answer. I don't know if it's the best solution, but at least it's working.

```
this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['channel']));
```

This solve my problem.